# Auto Update Excel File, running Macro with Task Scheduler

Tags: vba, excel, macros, task, scheduler

I am trying to have an excel file open daily, update, and save. The file is on a remote desktop since it is pulling data from a program on the remote desktop. Not everyone has access to the remote desktop, but they can access the excel file.

The File is pulling data out of a software, running a macro to organize & filter. I would like to have this file open Daily in the morning, run the macro, then save and close the file. I have gotten task manager to open the file, but unsure how to the get macro to run, and what I need to add in order for the file to save itself.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at having Task Manager run a script instead of opening the file, and the script can open the workbook and launch the macro.

Comment: Thank you. I am a little unfamiliar with how that works but I will look into doing that. If you have any advice on how to help that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The vbscript that I use to launch a macro goes like this.  Sub ExcelMacroExample() 

  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Tables.xls", 0, false) 
  xlapp.visible = true
  xlApp.Run "UpdateAll"
  xlapp.activeworkbook.close
  xlApp.Quit 

  Set xlBook = Nothing 
  Set xlApp = Nothing 

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in pure Excel/VBA, you can actually send command line parameters to the workbook.  It's not the most straight-forward process.

If you create a `Workbook_Open` event **on the workbook object itself**, the code within this event will run every time you open Excel.

[image]

The trick, then is to have it only do your refresh tasks when you tell it to and quietly exit every other time.

Step 1:  create your event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Dim CmdRaw As Long
  Dim CmdLine, LastParam As String
  Dim Params As Variant

  CmdRaw = GetCommandLine     ' in our example, this will be /e/Refresh
  CmdLine = CmdToSTr(CmdRaw)
  Params = Split(CmdLine, "/")
  LastParam = Params(UBound(Params))

  If LastParam = "Refresh" Then
     Module1.RunAllOfThatAutomationJunk
  End If

End Sub
```

Again, this will only do the actual work if it gets a command-line argument where the last parameter is "Refresh."  You can make this whatever you want, of course.

This is the part that is not intuitive.  When you open your workbook in task manager, you have to open the Excel application with the command line parameter, along with your document:

```
excel.exe c:\MyLocation\MyFile.xlsm /e/Refresh
```

The `/e` is what triggers the command to be send to Excel, and you can see how the event parses this out.  You can put as many command line arguments as you want this way, between the slashes.

Bear in mind Excel.exe might actually be something like:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe"
```

But I didn't want to assume anything.

--EDIT--

This code also has to exist (in a module) to enable these features.  In the past, I tried adding it to the workbook VBA itself without success, but if it's in a separate module/class, it seems to work perfectly.

```
Declare Function GetCommandLine Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetCommandLineW" () As Long
Declare Function lstrlenW Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString As Long) As Long
Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (MyDest As Any, MySource As Any, ByVal MySize As Long)

Function CmdToSTr(cmd As Long) As String
Dim Buffer() As Byte
Dim StrLen As Long

   If cmd Then
      StrLen = lstrlenW(cmd) * 2
      If StrLen Then
         ReDim Buffer(0 To (StrLen - 1)) As Byte
         CopyMemory Buffer(0), ByVal cmd, StrLen
         CmdToSTr = Buffer
      End If
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: I had "CmdLine = CmdToSTr(CmdRaw)" CmdToSTr come up as not defined

Comment: Oops, my bad...  updating answer now.

Comment: So I get a Compile Error: Method or Data Member not found relating to the Private Sub Workbook Open() for Module1.RunAllOfThatAutomationJunk. I am not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Any chance you can post your spreadsheet to DropBox / GDrive or something similar?

Comment: I don't think I can access Dropbox from my work computer. I maybe be able to send it to myself and upload it later on

Comment: Is there something that I am missing that I would have to change in the VBA code you provided that is specific to my file & computer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PowerShell script that we use to open an Excel file, extract some worksheets to CSV and then exit. I hope it is helpful.

```
#
#  Extract worksheets from Excel into CSV files
#
$workingDir = Get-Location
$XL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$XL.Visible = $false
$XL.DisplayAlerts = $false

$inputFile = $workingDir.ProviderPath + '\Properties.xlsx'
write-debug $inputFile

$wb = $XL.Workbooks.Open($inputFile)

foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets)
{
    $outputName = $workingDir.ProviderPath + '\' + $ws.Name + '.csv'
    write-debug $outputName

    #
    #  The second argument is XlFileFormat enum.
    #  6 = xlCSV
    #  23 = xlCSVWindows
    #
    $ws.SaveAs($outputName, 6)
}
$XL.Quit()
```